# Image not getting displayed on Tkinter through Label widget

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I am using following code to display an image on my Tkinter GUI, but only a blank frame is getting displayed.

```
import Tkinter as tk class my_gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file=PATH_TO_GIF)
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = img)
        panel.grid()

app = my_gui()

app.mainloop()
```

However, the following code works:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file=PATH_TO_GIF)
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Any idea what the problem with the first script is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets you create are thrown away as soon as the `__init__()` function ends. To fix this, save them as instance variables with `self`:

```
import Tkinter as tk 
class my_gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=PATH_TO_GIF)
        self.panel = tk.Label(self, image = self.img)
        self.panel.grid()

app = my_gui()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Personally, I like saving the image as an attribute of the Label like `self.panel.image = img` better, since you don't fill up your namespace with variables that you don't need to reference anymore, there is a smaller chance of accidentally overwriting it with another image and you can be sure that the image stays around exactly as long as the Label.

Answer (score 0):

@SimranjotSingh, what are trying to do is display the image in a class.
The mainloop function is specifically meant for the parent window or frame. If you need to call the instance of your class you should call it like:

```
Instance_name = class_name(desired parameters)
```

However in your program you need to the image to a label and not directly to the root/window.

You can alse check out these:

[Attempting to add a simple image into a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747626/attempting-to-add-a-simple-image-into-a-label)

[How to add an image in Tkinter (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter-python-2-7)